# Grab the required part from an Image in Python and find the defective pixels in that part

Tags: python, opencv, python-imaging-library

I am working on a project, where I have to find defective pixels of a screen based on the Image of that screen. Now, I have used opencv and applied mask for the contours and got the screen area and also the defective pixels. But I am stuck at the point of finding the positions of the defective pixels. To find defective pixels I have used, red is the dominant color:

Now, I need to find the positions of the red pixels which are not appended in 'data_red' and within contour. Looking forward for a solution! Thanking you in advance.
    red=[i for i in Image_data]
    for i in red:
            if i>175:
                data_red.append(i)

[The image before applying the mask, after applying the mask, only the red part remains red and others become black](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PMaxu.jpg)

Now I need the red pixel positions to be displayed, which do not satisfy the condition, >175.

Comment: So I am assuming that this attached image is the input image? Now what output are you expecting ?

Comment: Its the by product, neither the input nor output but you can consider it as an input. I want to find the positions of the pixels which are less than 175 in the red part, not the black one. I also have the contour array of opencv. Is there any way to use the contour array as a boundary and find the positions within that

Comment: It would be better if you update your question with exact input and the expected output?

Comment: that is the exact input @ZdaR. My bad, i thought i have uploaded the masked one.

Comment: Ok, but what about expected output?

Comment: I need the pixel positions as output. The defective ones, means which do not satisfy the condition of >175 within the red region. I have contour array with me, but don't know how to extract the boundary conditions of the screen.

Answer (score 1):

Use **Numpy**.

```
import numpy as np

# get red from somewhere
red_np = np.array(red)
data_red = red_np[red_np > 175]

# and for the ones not appended
not_appended = np.argwhere(data_red <= 175)
```

This will return a numpy array with positions of all elements in the array data_red whose values were below 175.

Comment: but thats for the overall image. I need it within contour region. I have tried getting contour positions in terms of pixels, to get the boundaries, but it didn't help me. It would be appreciated, if you have any other suggestion.